# Tensorflow imports cause Heroku timeout (Django Python)

Tags: tensorflow, heroku

I'm using Heroku (free) to try to deploy a relatively simple neural network I made using Django. The problem is that when I import tensorflow to load the saved model, tf takes longer than 30 seconds to import, causing my single web worker to timeout and kill the page load.

Looking around on the internet, I found that using another worker thread might help with my slow import and model loading IO. However, I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, as the import chain from simply loading the page view spreads down to the tensorflow import. Trying to use basic Python threading within my app to put the imports and model loading in a different thread didn't help heroku load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that using python threading DID help get past the R12 heroku timeout, but I then had a confounding error: my Django `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting did not have the correct localhost url listed to run the site.